# Typescirpt pass Parameter<T> to function

Tags: typescript, generics

I currently have a function like this:

```js
async function initModule<T extends typeof MetadataStorageAdapter | typeof ValueStorageAdapter>(
        module: T,
        ...params: Parameters<T['initialize']>
): Promise<void> {
    await module.initialize(params);
}
```

Where both `MetadataStorageAdapter` and `ValueStorageAdapter` are namespaces that each export the type function `.initialize()`. However, `MetadataStorageAdapter.initialize()` takes a string as argument whereas `ValueStorageAdapter.initialize()` does not.

The way that I call `initModule()` is just the way that I want. It is `initModule(MetadataStorageAdapter, 'some-string')` and `initModule(MetadataStorageAdapter)`. However, I get an error in the line

```js
        await module.initialize(params);
```

How can I pass the `params` argument to the `.initialize()` function, so that I do not have to differentiate between the two variants of `.initialize()`.

Also, I am aware that `initModule()` does not really help, but the version in my project is more complex. I have simplified it for this example.

Comment: Could you include minimal definitions for `MetadataStorageAdapter` and `ValueStorageAdapter` and perhaps a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) link in the question? That would help people help you. (I'm being thrown by the `typeof`s in the generic constraint, for instance.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be `module.initialize(...params)` and not `module.initialize(params)`?  This wouldn't necessarily solve your problems (non-generic properties of generic objects are annoying, see [microsoft/TypeScript#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760)) but it might help to start with code that should work at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to use these definitions:

```
namespace MetadataStorageAdapter {
    export function initialize(x: string) { }
}

namespace ValueStorageAdapter {
    export function initialize() { }
}
```

Ostensibly the compiler *could* figure out that `T["initialize"]` should accept an argument list of type `Parameters<T["initialize"]>`, but often when you have property accesses of generic object types, they will be widened to their constraints too early for that.  (See [microsoft/TypeScript#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760) for a similar issue), When you call a function of type `T["initialize"]`, the compiler treats it as `(typeof MetadataStorageAdapter | typeof ValueStorageAdapter)["initialize"]`, or `((x: string) => void) | (() => void)`, a union of functions, which is not what you want.  Unions of functions [are callable with intersections of their arguments since TS3.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types), which means it will demand a string argument no matter what.  Boo.

One thing you can do is try to undo this widening by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to re-narrow `module.initialize` to a function that accepts `params`:

```
await (module.initialize as (...p: Parameters<T['initialize']>) => void)(...params);
```

---

Or, you could refactor your `initModule` signature to leave the type of the `initialize` method generic enough to be seen as something callable with `params`:

```
async function initModule<P extends any[]>(
    module: { initialize(...p: P): void },
    ...params: P
): Promise<void> {
    await module.initialize(...params);
}

initModule(MetadataStorageAdapter, "hello");
initModule(ValueStorageAdapter);
```

This is fairly similar to what you're doing.  If you need to constrain `module` further you could annotate it as type

```
{ initialize(...p: P): void } & 
  (typeof MetadataStorageAdapter | typeof ValueStorageAdapter)
```

instead, or you could make `module` a generic that extends such a type.  The point is that you should be able to rewrite the generics to a form where the compiler recognizes what you're doing as valid.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBZCAXEATEmDK6A9gE4gDmEAgjjOhMUgN4BQSbSEAHjCekgGYBXYPHQBLQsCRjgY8SAA2YgF4QAFJwBcSKOmIyyASiZIAvs3PNQkWAmQA1RYIgES5KjToMW7Dt14CwqISUjJyYooq6saMZhZIzIkgUACeIoEi4pLSsugohFiCChAA8gpYADwAKn50wFhQSOgpMBCE-KgY2LggrqQU1CC09EgAPk0tbR2OCs597oPDxAB8aqzsYAVFENpVADTrbAB0J3CkYFDaAAog5xj0UNUA2gDkYfJKqi8AusvMhtdiIQwGIoBAKgA3QhiLDLJiHJAgADuIDkSDUm0KxSO7win2QyXRJyOMGut3A92Ijyqr1xkS+v2MAF44VCYYY1MSzuAoIYANwWJKpdJCTIhHJyfJY8FXWoQeqNEDAFJPX5rXyY7baWJ0-Gc07XAFINlYMxIABk6OarXanUwOHwRH6HiGXjGExt0ycLidC089EMB18XPJF2u-0BwNB4JNcJ87GRqL4muxuqi+pJod5Ass7yl2zUaHtPXmA39xD2SAARAALCAKBSEKv85h5rbFNQzOa+suugN8oA)

Comment: The "await (module.initialize as (...p: Parameters<T['initialize']>) => void)(...params);" part did the trick!